# How to wrap an object and its member functions with c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm developing a c++ class to wrap an object and its member functions. As the object may be changed, so I'm thinking if it is possible to use some mechanism to do so, such as template. Here is an example:

```
class ObjectA
{
public:
    void funcA1(double);
    void funcA2(int, char);
private:
    int value;
};

class ObjectB
{
public:
    void funcB1(double);
    void funcB2(int, char);
private:
    int value;
    float point;
};
```

Now I need to develop a class, which can easily wrap the `ObjectA` or the `ObjectB`. It is for sure that `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` don't inherit any parent class and they must have two functions, the names of functions are not the same but the parameters must be the same, just like `funcA1` `funcB1` and `funcA2` `funcB2`.

I'm thinking the code as below should work.

```
template<typename T, typename funcAT, typename funcBT> // T: Object, funcAT: Object::funcA, funcBT: Object::funcB
class Wrapper
{
    // ...
};
```

Well, if the code works, is there some method to make more constraint? For example, how to make sure that `funcAT` must belong to the `T`, instead of other functions? how to make sure that `funcAT` must have only one parameter `double`, instead of other cases?

What I mean is:

```
ObjectA objA;
Wrapper<objA, objA::funcA1, objA::funcB1> wrapper; // no error
Wrapper<objA, other_funcA, other_funcB> wrapper; // ERROR
```

Comment: If you wrap the classes without any type-erasure like that your wrappers will still be two different types, one for ObjectA and another for ObjectB. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @super  You mean when I compile, it will generate two different wrappers? this is OK for me. I want to develop only one class `Wrapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member function pointers can go directly as template parameters:

```
template<typename T, void (T::*f1)(double), void (T::* f2)(int, char)>
class Wrapper
{
    // ...
};

Wrapper< ObjectA, &ObjectA::funcA1, &ObjectA::funcA2> w;
```